MySQL Timeout Issue in Production due to left join
I'm working on an application that has an issue in production where one query throws a timeout. The app uses MySQL.
SELECT
    `tags`.*,
    COUNT( ct.contact_id ) AS contacts_count 
FROM
    `tags`
    LEFT JOIN `contact_tag` AS `ct` ON `tags`.`id` = `ct`.`tag_id` 
WHERE
    `tags`.`company_id` = 1068 
    AND `tags`.`category` = 1 
    AND `tags`.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
GROUP BY
    `tags`.`id` 
ORDER BY
    `tags`.`id` DESC

so I split the query in two:
This first query works fine:
SELECT
   tags.id
FROM
    tags
WHERE
    tags.company_id = 1068 
    AND tags.category = 1 
    AND tags.deleted_at IS NULL 
GROUP BY
    tags.id
ORDER BY
    tags.id DESC
LIMIT 20

with this query I got the following tags ids:

294610,286349,286333,286332,286331,286330,268187,268175,265225,265224,265223,260136,257287

Then this second query the first time always takes 6 seconds and then 300ms:
SELECT 
   tag_id, 
   COUNT(com_tag.contact_id) AS communications_count
FROM 
   contact_tag as com_tag
WHERE 
   tag_id IN (294610,286349,286333,286332,286331,286330,268187,268175,265225,265224,265223,260136,257287)
GROUP BY 
   tag_id;

The result of this query is:

The last query with explain we have:



id
select_type
table
partitions
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
filtered
Extra




1
SIMPLE
com_tag
NULL
ref
contact_tag_contact_id_tag_id_unique,
contact_tag_tag_id_foreing
4
const
25933
100.00
Using index condition







contact_tag_tag_id_foreing









contact_tag table definition is:
CREATE TABLE `contact_tag` (
    `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `contact_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
    `tag_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
    `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `contact_tag_contact_id_tag_id_unique` (`contact_id`,`tag_id`),
    KEY `contact_tag_tag_id_foreign` (`tag_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `contact_tag_contact_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_id`) REFERENCES `contacts` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `contact_tag_tag_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tags` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2477082 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci


'The query uses an index,' - which of the 3 published queries are you referring to. also please add explain for the query and table definitions as text

How many tag_id's do you have in tag_id IN (1, 2, 3...) ?  MySQL needs to count them for every one of them, and that can take some time.

Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?, and table definitions as text is missing...

Do you want the explain as text definition?

Yes, the output of EXPLAIN <select statement>,    and SHOW CREATE TABLE contact_tag,  in TEXT format, because images are useless...

Great. Added as changes

Why is count() slow, when explain knows the answer?, It simply takes about 6 seconds to read those 25933 the first time, the seconds time those rows are in your cache, so they can be counted quicker. For more details ask at dba.stackoexchange.com.

reverse the order of your contact_id, tag_id index, and include contact_id is not null in your query. Then it can perform the entire query using the index and no paging to read every single row that matches.

You haven't included the table definitions, but from the name of this index contact_tag_contact_id_tag_id_unique I assume you have an index like this:
UNIQUE contact_tag_contact_id_tag_id_unique (contact_id, tag_id)
That index isn't usable since contact_id isn't specific. But, you have specific tag_id, so reversing the order of that index to:
UNIQUE contact_tag_tag_id_contact_id_unique (tag_id, contact_id)
would allow that index to be used. It's then possible to filter out any NULL contact_id. If you don't have NULL in contact_id, you can probably just use COUNT(*) instead, so I assume you do have some.
Either way, you can write the query like this:
SELECT 
   tag_id, 
   COUNT(*) AS communications_count
FROM 
   contact_tag as com_tag
WHERE 
   tag_id IN (294610,286349,286333,286332,286331,286330,268187,268175,265225,265224,265223,260136,257287) AND
   contact_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
   tag_id;

EDIT
All that said, you may just get faster results using a subquery
I am assuming tags.id is unique, so you can eliminate the GROUP BY
SELECT
    `tags`.*,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `contact_tag` WHERE `contact_tag`.`tag_id` = tags.id) AS contacts_count
FROM
    `tags`
WHERE
    `tags`.`company_id` = 1068 
    AND `tags`.`category` = 1 
    AND `tags`.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
ORDER BY
    `tags`.`id` DESC


THIS is not the ANSWER !

Statistics
MySQL uses statistics to optimize queries. Make sure your stats are
up to date. you can run
ANALYZE TABLE contact_tag;
to update the statistics

Profiling
Show us the profiling from your query with these steps and post us the results
mysql> SET profiling = 1;
mysql> SELECT 1; -- run your query
mysql> show profile;
mysql> show profile ALL;
mysql> SET profiling = 0;


